# Unable to subclass UILabel: Unrecognized selector sent to UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, tttattributedlabel

I'm using CocoaPods to import some things. Right now I'm trying to use `TTTAttributedLabel`, which is a rich subclass of `UILabel`, allowing for URL-clicking etc.

Now, I'm having trouble getting my app to recognise that my labels are actually instances of `TTTAttributedLabel`, and not regular `UILabel`'s.

In my .xib, I have dragged a regular `UILabel` into my view, then edited the class of the label like this:

[image: xib class]

It did autocomplete the name for me, so I know it knows about the class. Then, I have dragged a connection from the xib to the view's class, like this:

[image: connection]
It specifies itself as a `TTTAttributedLabel` automatically, because it recognises that that's what it is, or else it would've said `UILabel`.

Since I've specified `use_frameworks!` in my `podfile`, I have to import the class, so in the top of my view's class, I have `import TTTAttributedLabel`.

Now, when I try to use the label, it autocompletes likes this:
[image: autocomplete]
With the correct class, `TTTAttributedLabel`.
But when I do this:

```
print("labBody: ", labBody)
```

it prints out this:

```
labBody:  <UILabel: 0x7fa754c86710; frame = (16 459; 42 21); text = 'Label'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60000029cf20>>
```

thinking it's a UILabel. If I try to access any of the `TTTAttributedLabel`-specific variables or functions, it still autocompletes them for me:

```
labBody.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue
```

But when using these on runtime, the entire app crashes, saying this:

```
 -[UILabel setEnabledTextCheckingTypes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdfc7c59300
```

Am I blind? Why is this not working? This is what I've always been doing. I might be having a hard Tuesday..
I have tried all the regular stuff, cleaning, deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, deleting the app from the device before running again..

I have even used `TTTAttributedLabel` before, I know it works. The only thing that's new is that this is my first time using `use_frameworks!`.. Does that affect the .xib? Making it unable to know about the subclass, or something..?

Comment: Look at your console; are you getting a warning "unrecognised class TTTAttributedLabel in. In file" or something like that? What module is showing below the custom class in your nib file?

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh damn, you're right! I didn't even notice. It says `Unknown class _TtC16MyApp18TTTAttributedLabel in Interface Builder file.`. What does this mean?

Comment: The reason you can easily see the auto completion for TTTAttributeLabel methods is: you have declared it as TTTAttributedLabel. Even IF the implementation of that variable was a UILabel, it would still be considered by the compiler as TTTAttributedLabel, thus you won't get a warning from your compiler. And of course you can assign a UILabel to TTTAttributedLabel, as this is the superclass.

Comment: Have you tried to Clean the entire project. Quit xCode and perform again a pod install and pod update? Make sure that the pod is included to your build target. Now reopen the project and build it first (build and run not required). Now head to your xib-file. Select the class for UILabel and press enter! Now click somwhere else in the interface builder to make sure the class change is used. Save xib and give it one more try.

Comment: @Lepidopteron Still not working, sadly.. And when I googled `Unknown class .. in Interface Builder file.`, I get a lot of suggestions to fix the `Module` in IB, but the module is correct. It says "Current - MyApp". In the dropdown, I can choose "MyApp", no difference. I have tried hitting enter inside both fields, I have removed TTTAttributedLabel from my podfile and reinstalled the pods back and forth now. I have removed the labels and re-added them. I have cleaned derived data, restarted xcode and restarted my computer. Now it's time for me to restart my head, so I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: I would expect the module to be "TTTAttributedLabel"

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh! I've never had to use another module than "MyApp" before. Then again, I've never used ’use_frameworks!’ either. Are they connected? It's weird though, I didn't get that module up in the drop down list.. maybe it will autocomplete the name if I start typing it.. I'll try it tomorrow!

Comment: @Paulw11 Tried now, still no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea exactly *why* this worked, but I assume it has something to do with this pod being in Objective-C and something about binding and loading Obj-C stuff..

Anyway, all I had to do was to wrap the object in a new local class.
[image: newclass]
and then change the class of my labels in the .xib-file to this class instead of `TTTAttributedLabel` (and the outlets in my view's class, obviously).

No need to do anything else than creating this class, it doesn't need to contain anything.

I did read something about setting a flag, like a `load ObjC`-flag, I didn't try it. I thought that that solution might also load a lot of other Object-C stuff I didn't need/want to load..

Comment: This saved my day. I spent around 2-3 hours behind this issue. Creating an empty class done the job for me.